# How to make js function file and how to call that file through ajax to do that function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call a file through ajax which has a javascript function in it. I'm able to get the contents of the file (when I alert it it shows everything written in that file) but I don't know how to call the function in the file.

My code is:
To call ajax to run that function:

```
if($("#essentialbtn").click(function() {
    $.ajax("essentialplan.php").done(function(data) {
       alert(data);
    });
}));
```

File: (named essentialplan.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    localStorage.setItem('essentialPlan', $('#essential').text());     
    localStorage.setItem('essentialPrice', $('#priceA').text());

    window.location.href = "http://incrediblewebpages-com.stackstaging.com/convertion%20bubble/conversion2.php"; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to a script file and use [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). Make sure to remove the `<script>` tags also.

Also remove the `if()`

**essentialplan.js**

```
localStorage.setItem('essentialPlan', $('#essential').text());     
localStorage.setItem('essentialPrice', $('#priceA').text());

window.location.href = "http://incrediblewebpages-com.stackstaging.com/convertion%20bubble/conversion2.php";
```

Click code:

```
$("#essentialbtn").click(function() {
    $.getScript("essentialplan.js");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to remove the script tags from your `essentialplan.php` file so the content/ response data should be this:

```
localStorage.setItem('essentialPlan', $('#essential').text());     
localStorage.setItem('essentialPrice', $('#priceA').text());

window.location.href = "http://incrediblewebpages-com.stackstaging.com/convertion%20bubble/conversion2.php";
```

Then, you can use `eval()` :

```
$("#essentialbtn").click(function() {
    $.ajax("essentialplan.php").done(function(data) {
       eval(data);
    });
})
```

or you can use `$.getScript()` :

```
$("#essentialbtn").click(function() {
    $.getScript("essentialplan.php").done(function(script, textStatus) {
        // do whatever you want to do
    });
});
```

P.S: You don't need if() to set a JQuery click event
P.S (2) : the callback on the `$.getScript` function is optional